Equivalent group delay of a cascade system using multiple stages of IIR filters + downsampling
I'm trying to determine the equivalent group delay that a "broad band" signal (i.e not a tone) will experience while going through a cascade of IIR filters + decimation.
The code below shows one such system with 2 stages. Each stage decimates after IIR filtering.
So far my approach has been sending an impulse through the cascaded system and using the output as the numerator coefficients of a FIR filter to measure the group delay this way.

Is this approach correct?
Any other suggestions on how to estimate this?

I found there is a [D,FsOut,B] = outputDelay(cascade(Hd1,Hd2),'Fc',500) function introduced in Matlab R2022a that perhaps would be able to give the result directly but I'm not sure how to introduce the decimation steps and also it only seems to allow introducing a single carrier frequency Fc and not a whole band.
I didn't directly sum the group delays of each IIR stage because they are working at different sampling rates and there is a decimation step in-between. I'm not sure if it is possible to map the group delay at one sampling frequency with the group delay at another sampling frequency so I can simply add the group delays over the common frequency range for both sampling frequencies.
    % 1st decimation stage
    Fs1 = 48000;    % Input sampling Frequency
    N     = 8;      % Order
    Fpass = 3000;   % Passband Frequency
    Apass = 1;      % Passband Ripple (dB)
    Astop = 80;     % Stopband Attenuation (dB)
    
    h1  = fdesign.lowpass('N,Fp,Ap,Ast', N, Fpass, Apass, Astop, Fs1);
    Hd1 = design(h1, 'ellip');
    
    % 2nd decimation stage
    Fs2 = 12000;    % Intermediate sampling Frequency
    N     = 8;      % Order
    Fpass = 700;   % Passband Frequency
    Apass = 1;      % Passband Ripple (dB)
    Astop = 80;     % Stopband Attenuation (dB)
    
    h2  = fdesign.lowpass('N,Fp,Ap,Ast', N, Fpass, Apass, Astop, Fs2);
    Hd2 = design(h2, 'ellip');
    
    Fs3 = 3000;   % Final sampling Frequency
    
    %signal creation
    impulse_duration_ms = 250;
    impulse_duration_samp = impulse_duration_ms*Fs1/1000;
    impulse = zeros(1,impulse_duration_samp);
    impulse(1) = 1;
    
    % Filtering and decimating by 4
    decimated_by_4 = filter(Hd1,impulse);
    decimated_by_4 = decimated_by_4(1:Fs1/Fs2:end);
    
    % Filtering and decimating by 16
    decimated_by_16 = filter(Hd2,decimated_by_4);
    decimated_by_16 = decimated_by_16(1:Fs2/Fs3:end);

    h = fvtool(decimated_by_16,1,'Fs',Fs3);
    set(h, 'Analysis', 'grpdelay');
    set(h, 'GroupDelayUnits', 'Time');


That's kinda the experimental approach.  There is a theoretical approach where you calculate equations for the group delay as a function of frequency.  Then add the group delay for each section of the cascaded system.

A different approach would be to cascade dsp.FIRDecimator and dsp.iir for each stage. When Cascading all stages you could use matlab grpdelay function to get the overall group delay. e.g.: dcm_stage1=4; downsample=ds.FIRDecimator(dcm_stage1,1);iir_stage1=dsp.iir(b,a); stage1=cascade(iir_stage1,downsample) ...

@robertbristow-johnson I don't know how to reconcile the 2 calculated group delays each operating at a different sampling frequency before summing them. Assume each group delay has 1024 samples. Do I select a common frequency band based on the smallest sampling frequency and interpolate the group delay corresponding to the highest sampling frequency in this band to be able to sum?

@Irreducible normally dsp.FIRDecimator not only discards samples, it also performs an anti-aliasing FIR filtering which I don't have anywhere on my system. Unless I could replace this FIR filter coefficients by a simple delta at the origin to bypass the FIR part. Is this what you mean why the 1 in ds.FIRDecimator(dcm_stage1,1) ?

Okay VMMF, I didn't realize you had two different sample rates.  So you have to first convert the same common frequency in Hz into the two different normalized frequencies (which will be by dividing by their respective sample rates).  Then you have to evaluate the group delay in samples for each filter, and then convert to delay in seconds or milliseconds.  Then you can add the two delays.

@VMMF you are right dsp.FIRDecimator is used as a anti-aliasing FIR with downsampling, however, as you pointed out, the second argument are the numerator coefficients. Setting them to one just leaves you with a dsp-object that just performs the downdsampling. This allows you to create the cascaded objects which you want and to use the matlab function to investigate the characteristics of your multi-rate system.

group delay is defined at a specific frequency. When working on broadband signals the group delay of such broad signal cannot possibly be a single number any more. It's a function across the signal bandwidth. How you then average such potentially dispare values of the function group delay is up to you. Average? worst? best? median? harmonic average?

think it this way: what is the group delay of a DVB-T signal over 8MHz composed of 8000 single tone carriers? the answer is the list of group delays of each carrier. If the channel is flat, and all good then one could say they all look the same and come up with a single figure. But through distorted channels then what? this is why OFDM places 'pilot' tones not carrying payload scattered across the broadband signal and such test carriers are used to define a custome figure of merit to tell how close or dispare are.

@JohnBofarullGuix I'm interested in the group delay of every frequency component inside the broad band, in other words looking at the graph. Ideally I would like it to be as flat as possible in the band of interest, a good metric would be was is the greatest variation in the group delay in the band

you say you have to measure group delay along a broadband signal but in the code you supply in your question you simulate a 250ms pulse signal, which is not broadband. Yes you can go up the 10th harmonic and say that is a broadband signal but it is not, a 250ms pulse train is a single carrier narrow band single with 1cand only 1 carrier frequency. ADSL, 5G, 4G, DVB-T .. those are broadband signals : thousands of carriers with tiny spacing that when freq SPAN not narrow enough look like a continuous broadband. FM can also be made broadband with large deviation. Military use FSK also huge band.

So 1st generate an OFDM signal with a large amount of close enough carriers, or an FSK with really far apart frequecncies, or an analog FM with unusual high freq deviation. Otherwise you just have 1 carrier and the group delay of that carrier is all you need to measure.

So, let's recap: 1. a signal is (in general) considered broadband when |fmax-fmin| > 10. This thresold could be 5 or 20 but the tips of the spectrum are signal, desired information, not noise, not harmonics. Harmonics are distortion, a by-product, not wanted 2. A single pulse train with interval is a single carrier Base Band signal. 250ms it's very lof freq audio! to really create a broadband signal first take off, meaning, mosdulate up to a central frequency where there's enough frequency around that central frequency to build something broadband .


Choose a broadband modulation. Square pulses at riny different rate steps will stumble upon adjacent pulses and cause a lot of distortion. Choose a broad band modulation so fmax-fmin >>10 4. then you can sample band points and define an equivalent group delay


Important that didn't mention above :  Qualcomm CDMA signal are also broadband, with faster enough than central carrier codes used. Spread Spectrum signals are also broadband indeed.

Qualcomm gave up on CDMA for massive cellular because coding only, even with well designed orthogonal coding, if no further modulating signals, noise grows up too high limiting the amount of phones per cell ... compared to OFDM based systems.

correction : where i said broadband signals are |fmax-fmin| > 10 should have said |fmax-fmin|/fc > 10 ; fc central carrier fc=(fmax-fmin)/2

@JohnBofarullGuix My code shows an impulse(delta) at the origin which has energy on all frequency components up to Fs/2. My Fs is 48 KHz and I'm working with an audio signal. You can use this to determine the impulse response of the system. To me that is in fact as broad band as you can get at 48 KHz in the sense that is not a simple discrete frequency component like with an infinite cosine in time. Do you understand now? No modulations involved here, no GHz frequencies

ok thanks for the clarification

Rick Lyons outlines an effective Group Delay calculation in "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" 3rd edition, page 830 (13-174) that proceeds as follows:
Generate the impulse response for the system (apply [1, 0, 0, 0 ....] at the input and generate the output until the resulting tail is insignificant. (I review this in dB to really evaluate to see if it below -100 dB or whatever my system dynamic range is; all converging IIR systems will ultimately have an insignificant impulse response eventually even though we refer to them as "infinite").
From the impulse response, zero pad if you would like a better estimate of the group delay result (which is a continuous function) and then use the FFT as follows to determine the Group Delay:
$$GD = real\bigg\{\frac{\text{FFT}\{n (h[n])\}}{\text{FFT}\{h[n]\}} \bigg\}$$
Rick provides one explanation as to how this works in his text, and Julius O. Smith provides further details here:https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters06/Numerical_Computation_Group_Delay.html
As Rick and Julius both caution, there is a condition where the denominator can go to zero. The grpdelay function in Matlab uses this technique and sets the result to be zero in this case.
It's an interesting study of the phase properties of reverse filters.

Thank you for your valuable answer Dan! However, I would like you to expand it a bit before I can consider it as the accepted answer. It seems like your numerator hr = h .* [0:M]; is the ramped h polynomial, can you confirm this? Am I supposed to use this equation on the final h I obtained? Is this not equivalent to computing the group delay on this h in Matlab just like I did? Furthermore, the equation you have included is for the FIR/IIR case but there's a faster equation just for IIR case which uses C = conv(B,fliplr(conj(A))); and Cr = C.* [0:M]. I don't see a way to use it though. Thanks!

It’s not h.*[0:M] but n.*h[n]: multiply each coefficient by its index. The FFT of this ends up being j times the derivative of the frequency response with respect to frequency (but that’s how it’s derived which I wasn’t getting into, that is well explained on Julius page I linked or Rick’s book if you have it. That last formula you mention in your comment is not the GD but the C polynomial Julius gives in the path to deriving the same formula I gave.

Hi Dan, multiply each coefficient by its index is exactly what i meant, I was just using the exact notation in the link you provided

Not sure if you saw this already, but this may help you if not: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/filters06/Group_Delay_Computation_grpdelay_m.html#sec:grpdelay
